# Adding a marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to add another marker to my map.

```
{
    //google map functionality
    if($("#map_canvas").length > 0) {
        initGmap(52.089115,-7.619437, 15);
    }

}); // END jQuery(document).ready
```

Does anyone have any idea how I cna do this, I have looked up on google but seem to be doing it wrong.

Comment: Please refer to the google maps API page - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Answer (score 0):

To add a [new marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple?hl=es) you ned to create it like this:

```
// Barcelona coordinates
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(2.19, 40.4);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
```

Check [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) if you need multiple markers.